# Inserting at the head of the linkedList C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function that would let me insert nodes at the head of my list.

This is what I have so far, but I need some help and suggestions. Could you please shed some light? since It is almost thanksgiving day and I don't want to be tortured with this exercise anymore?

```
void List::insertAtHead(int addData) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL){
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    else
    {
        head = n;
    }
```

Comment: Like your previous posting this code looks good to me. You should at least attempt to explain what you think the problem is.

Comment: Only problem I see is a missing closing brace on the function...

Comment: I just have trouble understanding this concept (linkedlist) and because I'm new to C++ I like to get some feedback on what I do because I know that sometimes I don't do it right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite `node*`, it could be simplified:

```
void List::insertAtHead(int addData){
    node* n = new node;
    n->next = head;
    n->data = addData;

    head = n;
}
```

According to the suggestion of Zac Howland:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int data,node* next)
        :data(data)
        ,next(next)
    {}
};

void List::insertAtHead(int addData){
    head = new node(addData,head);
}
```

Comment: I think I'll repeat my comment to the other answer, it's pretty clear that `nodePtr` is a typedef for `node*`.

Comment: And if `node` defines a constructor that takes a `data` and `next` parameter, it could be simplified even more.

Comment: @Zac Howland: Yup, that would have been another advantage of SSCCE, despite that assumed typedef.